# Mapping @SecondaryTable different tables with same column names

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables related with the `@SecondaryTable` annotation

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cRequestHeader")
@SecondaryTable(name = "cRequestAccess", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cRequestHeader_fk"))
public class RequestHeader {

@Column(name = "DeviceType")
    private String deviceType;

@Column(name= "DeviceType", table = "cRequestAccess")
    private String requestAccessDeviceType;
}
```

The `cRequestAccess` table also has a `DeviceType` column, and I want to map that value into the `requestAccessDeviceType` attribute in the `RequestHeader` class, but it's mapping into `requestAccessDeviceType` the value of `DeviceType` of the `cRequestHeader` table, not the `DeviceType` of the `cRequestAccess`.